# Number counter to count even if non number characters exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number counter which works if the input if only a number. However, this might not always be the case, for example, instead of `16000` a user may input `16,000`.

With my current setup, the ticker works if it's just a number, but how can I prevent it from breaking if a non number character exists?

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.count{
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3C3C3C;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<span class="count">16000</span>
<br>
<span class="count">16,000 +</span>
```

**Edit:**

I'm not looking to strip any characters, if non number characters do exist, I want them to remain static, but numbers to still count.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you could use a regular expression to remove any non-numeric characters from the string, like this:

```
Counter: $(this).text().replace(/\D/g, '')
```

> I want the numbers to count up and non number chars to stay as is

In that case you'd need to perform the above, as the counter will only work with numeric values, and then you need to re-format the value when you display it again in the `step` handler function, something like this:

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text().replace(/\D/g, '')
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(numberWithCommas(Math.ceil(now)));
    }
  });
});

function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```css
.count {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3C3C3C;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<span class="count">16000</span><br />
<span class="count">16,000 +</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question, I'm not looking to strip the characters out. For example in the case of `16, 000 + `, I want the numbers to count up and non number chars to stay as is. Of course with my current approach, it just errors

Comment: That's pretty neat, cheers. Still wondering how it would work if there's text appended to the number i.e. "16,000 test" will result in "16, 000". Anyway to keep the text there?

Comment: In that case It'd be best to put the number to increment in it's own element, separate from the other text. For example `<p><span class="count">16,000</span> test</p>`

Comment: Yeah, just tested that and it works too. So it's not possible via JS (or not recommended via JS)? Just that in my CMS, I've provided one textfield where the user can input the content they want to count up. I can `preg_replace` the field value for number characters and non number characters, but unsure if this approach is sustainable?, especially if non numerical characters exist between numbers

Answer (score -1):

Well my approach on this would be a little different, let me know if something like this would be "doable"

Goes by separating what is data from what is representation of data
Number from text basically.

I've build this sandbox, check it out and see if you understand what I attempted there.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-darkness-i0qks?fontsize=14

EDIT: This **will not** work nice with decimal places (in case you need it)